# Delete packages programmatically

Tags: package

I've tried this:

```
(setq pkg-list '(rust-mode lsp-mode))

(dolist (pkg pkg-list)
  (when (package-installed-p pkg)
    (package-delete pkg)))
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get any errors or it doesn't do what you wanted it to?

Comment: I get this `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument package-desc rust-mode)`. The code is working with `package-install`.

Comment: Put the error message in the question. Comments can be deleted at any time. As it stands now, the question risks being deleted because it is unclear. Describe what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a case like this you can inspect the function to see what it does with the `interactive` form. That is, use `C-h f package-delete`, then follow the link to the source, and then look at the `(interactive ...)` bit. You'll also see in the docstring that the function expects a cl struct.

The code for this function is a bit convoluted, but eventually you can see that it is looking up in `package-alist`. So you can use:

```
(dolist (pkg pkg-list)
  (when (package-installed-p pkg)
    (package-delete (car (cdr (assoc pkg package-alist))))))
```

Comment: This is wrong, the function expects a struct (which may be a vector, record, etc.).

Comment: So the documentation is wrong ? `Argument PKG-DESC is a full description of package as vector.`

Comment: @wasamasa You're right, it accepts a cl struct (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Structures.html)